# Find entry exit on intersect

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tracking, dlib

Im using the following code to find entry and exit count of the people.

```
 # check to see if the object has been counted or not
            if not to.counted:
                # if the direction is negative (indicating the object
                # is moving up) AND the centroid is above the center
                # line, count the object
                if direction < 0 and centroid[1] < H // 2:
                    totalUp += 1
                    to.counted = True

                # if the direction is positive (indicating the object
                # is moving down) AND the centroid is below the
                # center line, count the object
                elif direction > 0 and centroid[1] > H // 2:
                    totalDown += 1
                    to.counted = True
```

As per this code if the same person comes back and enters again, the entry count is still the same as the person has been counted already. I want to find the entry and exit count everytime when the person intersects the line. How do I sort it out?

Comment: What is the `to` object? If it's a class you define, you could keep track of `counted` as an `int` and increment `counted` with `to.counted+=1`. This would also require you get rid of the `if` statement, otherwise you'll only count at the instance `counted=0` or in your case `counted=False`

Comment: object is the person..

Comment: Add the code used to define `to` (including any class definition) to your question, that might make things a touch more clear for us to help and we can see exactly what you're working with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to do that would be to ignore the `counted` attribute entirely:

```
# if the direction is negative (indicating the object
# is moving up) AND the centroid is above the center
# line, count the object
if direction < 0 and centroid[1] < H // 2:
      totalUp += 1

# if the direction is positive (indicating the object
# is moving down) AND the centroid is below the
# center line, count the object
elif direction > 0 and centroid[1] > H // 2:
    totalDown += 1
```

This is assuming that your total counts are not per *person* but a grand total of occurrences. If that's the case, ignore the `if to.counted` because you don't care if they've been counted already, you just care if the conditions you've set have been satisfied

Comment: I tried doing so. It increments the count dramatically fast.

Comment: Is that expected behavior? If not, why not?

Comment: it is not the expected behaviour. Everytime when the person hits the line, either the entry or exit count should increase only once until he hits it again... if he hits it again, entry or exit count should increment once more...  it shall not increment constantly.

Comment: based on the `if` logic and available code, the *only* way the entry or exit values are incremented is if they satisfy one of the two conditions. Are you sure that the program is not finding those matches at a fairly high rate and so it *looks* like the count is increasing constantly? I would need to see your entire code to tell why the values are increasing at an unacceptable rate